# Python: Using function over multiple columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, dataframe

I am sure this question pops up often. However, I did not manage to derive an answer for this task after going through similar questions.

I have a dataframe of returns of multiple stocks and would need to run solely univariate regressions to derive rolling beta values.

The ols.PandasRollingOLS by Brad Solomon is very convenient for including the window/rolling. However, I did not manage to iterate the function over all the stock return columns.

I want this function to loop/iterate/go through all the columns of different stock returns.

In the following I am using code from the Project description https://pypi.org/project/pyfinance/ , as it should help to point my issue out clearer than my from my project.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pyfinance import ols
from pandas_datareader import DataReader

syms = {
     'TWEXBMTH': 'usd',
     'T10Y2YM': 'term_spread',
     'PCOPPUSDM': 'copper'
     }


data = DataReader(syms.keys(), data_source='fred',
                   start='2000-01-01', end='2016-12-31')\
     .pct_change()\
     .dropna()\
     .rename(columns=syms)

y = data.pop('usd')


rolling = ols.PandasRollingOLS(y=y, x=data, window=12)

rolling.beta.head()


#DATE   term_spread copper  
#2001-01-01 0.000093    0.055448
#2001-02-01 0.000477    0.062622
#2001-03-01 0.001468    0.035703
#2001-04-01 0.001610    0.029522
#2001-05-01 0.001584    -0.044956
```

Instead of a multivariate regression I would like the function to take each column separately and iterate through the entire dataframe.

As my dataframe over 50 columns long, I would like to avoid being in the need of, writing the function that often, such as in the following (however, yielding the expected results):

```
rolling = ols.PandasRollingOLS(y=y, x=data[["term_spread"]], window=12).beta
rolling["copper"]= ols.PandasRollingOLS(y=y, x=data[["copper"]], window=12).beta["copper"]

#   term_spread copper
#DATE       
#2001-01-01 0.000258    0.055856
#2001-02-01 0.000611    0.064094
#2001-03-01 0.001700    0.047485
#2001-04-01 0.001778    0.040413
#2001-05-01 0.001353    -0.032264
#...    ... ...
#2016-08-01 -0.100839   -0.176078
#2016-09-01 -0.058668   -0.189192
#2016-10-01 -0.014763   -0.181441
#2016-11-01 0.046531    0.016082
#2016-12-01 0.060192    0.035062
```

Tries I have made ended often with "SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument" as for the following:

```
def beta(r):
    z = ols.PandasRollingOLS(y=y, x=r, window=12);
    return z
```

Comment: in your beta function `y` is not defined

Comment: I believe it is a few lines above y = data.pop('usd') or I am just not able to identify the issue with y.

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment. Change `z = ols.PandasRollingOLS(y=y, x=r, window=12)` to `z = ols.PandasRollingOLS(y, x=r, window=12)`, what is y?